# How to generate all possible combinations of a 24 digit binary number?

Tags: minimax

I basically have a 24 digit number and I need to get every combination of that number with 1's and 0's I know that there is over 16,700,000 possible combinations. I need to get every single possible combination for a minimax algorithm game that I am developing. If you have an algorithm for this that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Stuff like this is all over Google, please look there before asking people to do your searching for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MiniMax for dots and dashes game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902809/minimax-for-dots-and-dashes-game)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate an unsigned int from 0 to 2^24-1:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 1U<<24; ++i)
{
    // do something with LS 24 bits of i ...
}
```

This will give you all possible bit patterns in the bottom 24 bits of `i`.